# Time travel Choose your own adventure-type series

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

This was a series of books where the reader travels through time, usually to the past (I know of one where the reader was sent to the future) to solve some mystery.

- In one the goal was to learn the fate of an escaped slave from the American South. The disappeared slave was a male, named Thomas *something*.
- In another the reader was sent to find the wreck of a Spanish galleon carrying a fortune in silver.

There was only one "successful" ending per story, if the reader was not careful he might end up trapped in a loop from one period to another unable to make any progress- what the series referred to as "stranded in time".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the [*Time Machine*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/55697-time-machine) series of gamebooks. The tagline for the series was...

> "*Your decision can lead you to safety or leave you **stranded in time!**".*

---

Book #4 ([*Sail With Pirates*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Time-Machine-4-Sail-Pirates-ebook/dp/B00DH29IF6)) had you hunting for a ship carrying silver

> Sail ahoy! Travel back to the 17th century and become a swashbuckling
>   pirate! Your mission is to find the wreck of the richest silver ship
>   ever to sink in the Caribbean Sea, and bring back some of the
>   treasure.

Book #5 ([*Civil War Secret Agent*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2903553-civil-war-secret-agent)) had you traveling around the deep south looking for Harriet Tubman.

> In 1859, a black man named Thomas Dean disappeared from the Jasper plantation in Maryland. A diary, recently discovered in an attic in Philadelphia, says that Thomas Dean, who was a slave, managed to escape from the cruel owners of the plantation with the help of Harriet Tubman. Did Harriet Tubman really help Thomas Dean? Or did he disappear in some other mysterious way? You must find Harriet Tubman and solve the mystery of Thomas Dean

Comment: Most of the details match, but the disappeared slave was a male, named Thomas something.

Comment: Yes! That is it.